# display error message in current popup (fetching record from db)

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to check mobile number is registered or not before going to enter otp page popup in my current popup page.

My controller

```
        public function VerificationOTP() {
        $postData = $this->input->post();
        if (isset($postData) && !empty($postData)) {
            $this->load->model('DoctorSearch');

            $exest = $this->DoctorSearch->checkPhoneNumber($postData,3);
            $data['mobileNumber'] = $this->input->post('mobileNumber');
            $data['loginOTP'] = ($this->input->post('loginOTP'))?$this->input->post('loginOTP'):'0';
            if ($exest['success']) {
                $data['mobilePrefix'] = $exest['mobilePrefix'];
                     $this->session->set_userdata('patmob',$exest['mobileNumber']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('patmobp',$exest['mobilePrefix']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('paturef',$exest['userRef']);

                $this->load->view('pages/otp',$data);

            } else {
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
                $msg .= 'Please Enter Registered Mobile Number';
                $msg .= '</div>';
                $this->session->set_flashdata("message", $msg);

                //$this->session->set_flashdata("message", '');
                redirect('verify-mobilenumber');
            }
        }

}

My script in view page;


              $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
        var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();
        $("form[name='mobnumber']").validate({
            rules: {
                mobileNumber: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            messages: {
                mobileNumber: {
                    required: "Enter Mobile Number"
                },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('verify-mobilenumber'); ?>",
                    data: {mobileNumber: mobileNumber},
                    success: function (result) {
                    if(result){
                     $("#enter-otp").modal('show');
                     $("#ver-num").html(mobileNumber);

                    }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I dont want to open #enter-otp popup untill given registered number. I want to show controller $msg .= 'Please Enter Registered Mobile Number'; in my current popup as fail message

Comment: check what result return in both condition and then
 if (result == (result when phone number is not entered))
{

}else{
  show popup
}

Comment: how to display error message (fetching from controller )in popup

Comment: you can use alert(result);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dataType in your $.ajax submit like this

in your view file

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="enter-otp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="OptBody" class="text-center">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url('verify-mobilenumber'); ?>",
           data: {mobileNumber: mobileNumber},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) {
             if(result.errors){
                $("#enter-otp").modal('show');
                $('#OptBody').append(result.errors);
                $("#ver-num").html(mobileNumber);
             }
           }
        });
    </script>
```

in your controller file, create an empty array that will hold the data you want to return and do json_encode to be able to return it back.

```
public function VerificationOTP() 
{
    $data = array('errors' => NULL);
    $postData = $this->input->post();
    if (isset($postData) && !empty($postData)) {
        $this->load->model('DoctorSearch');

        $exest = $this->DoctorSearch->checkPhoneNumber($postData,3);
        $data['mobileNumber'] = $this->input->post('mobileNumber');
        $data['loginOTP'] = ($this->input->post('loginOTP'))?$this->input->post('loginOTP'):'0';

        if ($exest['success']) {
            $data['mobilePrefix'] = $exest['mobilePrefix'];
            $this->session->set_userdata('patmob',$exest['mobileNumber']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('patmobp',$exest['mobilePrefix']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('paturef',$exest['userRef']);

            $this->load->view('pages/otp',$data);

        } else {
            $data['errors'] = "<p>Please Enter Registered Mobile Number</p>";
            //$this->session->set_flashdata("message", '');
            //redirect('verify-mobilenumber');
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: but how to display in popup? @Ryan

Comment: If you will look in the controller, I made an array $data with key as 'errors' with value 'message'. So in your ajax request, check if the $data['errors'] exist with result.errors. If yes, then you can display it like this ` $('#modalBody').append(result.errors); `